# If $\langle v,s\rangle+\langle s,v\rangle\leq \langle s,s\rangle$ for all $s\in S$, why is $v\in S^\perp$?

Tags: inner-products

Suppose you have a complex inner product space $V$, a subspace $S$, and some vector $v\in V$ such that 
$$\langle v,s\rangle+\langle s,v\rangle\leq\langle s,s\rangle$$ for all $s\in S$. How can you determine $v\in S^\perp$?

I jotted down that for a given $\epsilon>0$ and $s\in S$, there exists $c\in\mathbb{C}$ depending on such $\epsilon$ and $s$ such that $\langle cs,cs\rangle=|c|^2\|s\|<\epsilon$. Then
$$
\begin{align*}
\langle v,cs\rangle+\langle cs,v\rangle &=\bar{c}\langle v,s\rangle+c\langle s,v\rangle\\
&=\bar{c}\langle v,s\rangle+c\overline{\langle v,s\rangle}=2\Re(\bar{c}\langle v,s\rangle)\\
&\leq \langle cs,cs\rangle=|c|^2\|s\|<\epsilon
\end{align*}
$$

My hope was to somehow show $\Re\langle v,s\rangle$ and $\Im\langle v,s\rangle$ equal $0$, but it seems to be going in the wrong direction. Is there a more useful approach?

Comment: For starters you know that $v$ cannot be in $S$ because if it was, for some $s_0\in S$, $v = s_0$ and we would have that $\langle v, s_0\rangle + \langle s_0, v\rangle = 2\langle s_0, s_0\rangle \ge \langle s_0, s_0\rangle$.

Comment: I should amend my previous statement. $v$ could be the zero vector (but that would put it in $S^{\perp})$.

Comment: All this question, comments and answer are odd to me and I'm afraid either I or someone else is missing something: if we have a **complex** inner space then, in general, there is *no* an order relation between the inner product of elements and, of course, it is true in general that $$\langle v,s_o\rangle=\overline{\langle s_0,v\rangle}\neq\langle s_0,v\rangle$$ **unless** we're given a particular inner product is real non-complex...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:** Let $s\in S$ be a nonzero vector. Then $\varepsilon \alpha s\in S$ for every $\varepsilon>0$ and every $\alpha\in\mathbb{C}$. Hence $\langle v,\varepsilon \alpha s\rangle+\langle \varepsilon \alpha s,v\rangle\leq \langle \varepsilon \alpha s,\varepsilon \alpha s\rangle$ for all $\varepsilon>0$. Argue that $\mathrm{Re}(\langle \alpha s,v\rangle)=0$. As $\alpha$ is arbitrary, argue further that $\langle s,v\rangle=0$.

Comment: That was my inspiration for looking at $\langle v,cs\rangle+\langle cs,v\rangle$ since if $s\in S$, $cs\in S$. But I don't see how to relate that to showing $\langle v,s\rangle=0$.

Comment: @Kally I have elaborated the hint.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it a go.